# Percentage of "web requests" with HTTP Referer header set?

Tags: http, web-applications, http-headers, http-referer

I'm trying to change the layout of my webpage based on the HTTP Referer value (only the look-and-feel of the website would be changed and no security would be compromised).

Are there any studies carried out that gives us statistics on the HTTP Referer header?

For example, what percentage of web requests do not have this value set?

Comment: It'd be very weird statistics, as pages are innately different. Some are heavily featured in the search requests' results - and they obviously usually have a referrer set when somebody arrives there from that source.